# Firefox 4.0.1 crash intermittently and log out

Tags: firefox

Intermittently Firefox 4.0.1 is crashing on Ubuntu 11.04 and logging out. Sometimes it happens if I open an arbitrary website such as http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk I am NOT streaming any videos. Please let me know how to solve this or at least reasons behind this.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's an issue with your video card combined with newer Firefox technologies. Try turning off [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL):

1. Navigate to the URL `about:config`
2. Search for `webgl.disabled`
3. Make sure it's set to `true` (double-click on it if not)

If you want to debug the issue, you need to save the file `~/.xsession-errors` before login again in the desktop:

1. Switch to a virtual text console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login
3. Copy the file: `cp .xsession-errors name-of-desired-file`
4. Logout by executing `exit`
5. Switch back to the GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>F8</kbd> if <kbd>F7</kbd> didn't work)
6. Profit! (read the bottom of `name-of-desired-file` from step 3)